# VS Code: order of Java project elements

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How can I sort the elements of my java projects in VS Code ?
I already use the extension "Project Manager for Java" from Microsoft. This extension brings the view as seen in the image below. The extension neither have any settings for the sort order nor can I manually resort the elements. In Eclipse it's possible to resort those entries manually.
The image below shows the confusing *order* of one of my current java projects.

How can I fix that ?

[image: current sort order]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I manually change the order that folders are listed in Visual Studio Code Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968639/how-can-i-manually-change-the-order-that-folders-are-listed-in-visual-studio-cod)

Comment: No, it add a separate new panel with your desired order. I need the order within the java project manaager.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is such a setup yet, I filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/issues/692) that you can check out.