# Can I manually organize folders and files in VS Code's Explorer view?

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to organize folders and files manually in VS Code's Explorer view? If so, how?

Comment: I seriously considered voting to close this as a duplicate of [How can I manually change the order that folders are listed in Visual Studio Code Explorer?](/q/54968639/11107541), but the two questions are fundamentally different, as that one is clearly solely asking about folders, and this one is asking about files.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, for vanilla VS Code, all you have is `explorer.sortOrder`, which has the options: `default`, `filesFirst`, `foldersNestFiles`, `mixed`, `modified`, and `type`. Not what you're looking for.

See [Explorer / Opened Editors Sorting #27286](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27286), which tracks feature requests related to Explorer sorting. [Custom Sort Order in File Explorer #119207](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119207) was closed in favour of it, and it contains as open items, [Feature Request: api to custom files sort order at the sidebar #12345](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12345) and [Choose a sort order of directories and files according to the settings pattern #23231](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23231) among others.

Also historically related and which probably should have been closed in favour of #27286 (if it had existed back then): [Manually change the order of the folders and files that are listed in VSCode Explorer
#91843](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91843) and [Manually change the order of the folders and files that are listed in VSCode File Explorer
#95239](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95239).

As for extensions, see [@Brebber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726232/11107541) to [How can I manually change the order that folders are listed in Visual Studio Code Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54968639/11107541), which lists the following extensions which you might have luck with <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with these extensions)</sub></sup>:

- [kdcro101.favorites](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kdcro101.favorites)
- [oleg-shilo.favorites](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oleg-shilo.favorites)
- [sabitovvt.favorites-panel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sabitovvt.favorites-panel)
- [howardzuo.vscode-favorites](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=howardzuo.vscode-favorites)

For your reference / learning purposes, I found [@Brebber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9268485/brebber)'s answer by googling "`vscode extension manually sort explorer`", and the GitHub issue tickets by googling "`github vscode issues manually sort explorer`".

Fun fact: [#119207](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119207) was opened by one of the Stack Overflow staff, [@KyleMit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit).

Comment: Maybe the lack of the word "manually" in my search made me didn't find the right pages. I used "vs code folder view custom sort" as search keywords.

Furthermore, maybe my question is a duplicate from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968639/how-can-i-manually-change-the-order-that-folders-are-listed-in-visual-studio-cod), but the good answer is only the 3rd and [least voted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383705/10222643) there.

Answer (score -3):

It is a extension, name prettier. you can use it and i hope it will help you.

Comment: Prettier formats source code *in* files; it does not allow the displayed order of files in the Explorer view to be changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).